# '.json' parser which return schema of '.json' file

Tags: c++, json, parsing, schema

I want to display the schema of the `.json` file in the tree structure manner.
so, I need a `.json` parser in c++ which returns the schema of `.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use boost library.
sample code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

void load(const std::string &file_path)
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree pt;
    std::ifstream script;
    script.open(file_path.c_str());
    read_xml(script, pt);
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v,
                  config.get_child("config.servecies"))
    {
        std::cout
            << "First data: " << v.first.data() << std::endl
            << "Second data: " << v.second.data() << std::endl;
    }

}
```

run and give a file in XML format like :

```
    <config>
    <servecies>
        <module>file</module>
        <module>Admin</module>
        <module>HR</module>
        <notModule>MyNotModule</notModule>
    </servecies>
    </config>
```